# Can't fix "expects parameter 2 to be array, null given" error

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this errors in my code. Can someone help me?

> Warning: array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   /srv/disk1/2317571/www/loquium.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/foodica/functions/customizer/helpers-fonts.php
>   on line 506
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in
>   /srv/disk1/2317571/www/loquium.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/foodica/functions/customizer/helpers-fonts.php
>   on line 192
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in
>   /srv/disk1/2317571/www/loquium.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/foodica/functions/customizer/helpers-fonts.php
>   on line 192
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in
>   /srv/disk1/2317571/www/loquium.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/foodica/functions/customizer/helpers-fonts.php
>   on line 192
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in
>   /srv/disk1/2317571/www/loquium.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/foodica/functions/customizer/helpers-fonts.php
>   on line 192
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in
>   /srv/disk1/2317571/www/loquium.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/foodica/functions/customizer/helpers-fonts.php
>   on line 192

Line 190 - 196

```
    // Verify that the font exists
    if ( array_key_exists( $font, $allowed_fonts ) ) {
        // Build the family name and variant string (e.g., "Open+Sans:regular,italic,700")
        $family[] = urlencode( $font . ':' . join( ',', foodica_choose_google_font_variants( $font, $allowed_fonts[ $font ]['variants'] ) ) );
    }
}
```

Line 503 - 506

```
        $transient = json_decode($transient, true);
        $transient = array_reduce($transient['items'], 'foodica_transform_google_fonts_array', array());
        return apply_filters('foodica_get_google_fonts_from_api', $transient);
    }
endif;
```

Comment: what unclear is in the error message you are seeing? You need it to be show more times? :)

Comment: I wonder what a print on `$transient['items'])` may look like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use typecasting as shown below:

```
array_key_exists( $font, (array) $allowed_fonts );
```